# using mongo aggregation how to subtract the duraion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongo aggregation to aggregate based on "SWITCHID" and "STATUS" on finding the average duration where `"STATUS":"LIGHTS ON"` as well as  `"STATUS":"LIGHTS OFF"` but how do I subtract the `"STATUS":LIGHTS OFF"` duration

```
db.collection1.aggregate([    
    { "$group" : {     
        _id: {
            SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID",    
            STATUS: "$STATUS",
            avgduration: { $avg: "$duration" }      
        }    
    }}       
])
```

Output is:

```
"_id" : {
    "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS OFF",
    "avgduration" : 0.004166666666666667
    }
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
        "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
        "avgduration" : 0.009166666666666667
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
lightson avgduration - lightsoff avgduration
```

Comment: @veeram please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you. It can be optimized, but here is the idea:

```
db.getCollection('collection1').aggregate([    
{"$group" : {     
    _id: {
        SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID",    
        STATUS: "$STATUS"
    },
    avgduration: { $avg: "$duration" }
}},
{"$group" : {     
    _id: {
        SWITCHID: "$_id.SWITCHID"
    },
    on_minus_off: { $sum:{ "$cond": [
        { "$eq": [ "$_id.STATUS", "on" ] },
        "$avgduration",
        { $subtract: [ 0, "$avgduration" ] }
    ]}}
}}
])
```

Comment: {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a9a75a83711955836a8b4c2"),
 "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/5",
 "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30Z"),
 "RECEIVEDDATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:45Z"),
 "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
 "duration" : 0.008166
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a9a75aa3711955836a8b4c3"),
 "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/5",
 "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30Z"),
 "RECEIVEDDATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:45Z"),
 "STATUS" : "LIGHTS OFF",
 "duration" : 0.004166
}
total duration=0.008166-0.004166=0.004 this is my expected out put

Comment: total duration=0.008166-0.004166=0.004 this is my expected out put but not get the same out put please any suggestion